# Cannot run application SummitServices due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer

Tags: java, jdeveloper

The IntegratedWebLogicServer is running, but when I want to run the application, I get this error:

```
[10:21:31 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[10:21:31 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[10:21:31 PM] Unable to package module
[10:21:31 PM] Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
[10:21:31 PM] CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
#### Cannot run application SummitServices due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[10:21:31 PM] Cancel requested
[Application SummitServices stopped and undeployed from IntegratedWebLogicServer]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the JDK in a path that doesn't have a space in it. (not under "program files"). Also make sure you have a full JDK and not just a JRE that JDeveloper has access to.